# modify/access python instance from external script or command

Tags: python, instance, external

I have a main python code running (at startup) with an instance of a class in it. I would like to be able to modify this instance (its arguments) when I want (as a user). The idea is to be able to modify it without disturbing the main code or forcing it to read an external script every 2 seconds.  So, I would be able to run a bash command or a new python script that will modify this instance created in the main running script.

I use python 3 and already though/tried different things:

- write a method with an opened socket listening in the class corresponding to the instance. Seems overkill to me.
- be able to access the instance from its memory address with some tools such as ctypes and id. But I got errors in this way (Segmentation fault)

from terminal 1:

```
>>> a='c'
>>> hex(id(a))
'0x7fc9f825a378'
```

from terminal 2:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> d = (ctypes.c_char).from_address(0x7fc9f825a378)
>>> d
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So, how can I modify an instance in a running script from my archlinux os as a user?

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Seems like you want to [share memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) between processes?

Comment: The `id()` functions returning the address of the object is an implementation detail of cpython that you should not be using. And your object is in a different process, you can't access the memory space of one process from another - that would be a security violation. Use shared memory.

Comment: Many long-running programs reload their configuration from disk when they receive a signal (e.g. SIGHUP). You could implement something similar.

Comment: ok, looking for shared memory, seems the best solution for what I want to do, thanks. Thanks VPfB for your reply, however I don't think this is relevant for what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I did have a look at everything I could find about python share memory. But I did not find any solution to just share a dictionary or a *"normal"* array on my POSIX system.

- **sysv_ipc** or **posix_ipc** use buffers for strings, complicating everything (needs parsing).
- **multiprocessing** permits to do it but from the same script, there is no id/key to access it from another python instance.
- **SharedArray** do it but with numpy arrays.

Do you know a shared memory python library that permits to simply share an object such as dictionary or normal list?

Thanks for your time.